# clear timeout in react if component state changes

Tags: reactjs

I have code using react hooks that is fetching some data from an API after a search value has been entered.

I am trying to activate a Timeout that will stop in case the value of `const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);`changes.

I am not able to find out the way to do it, I can activate it when the use effect for fetching the information is activated, but I can not deactivate it in case new information is found.

In a nutshell:
I would like to know how to clearTimeout in case `searchResults` has value.

My code looks like:

```
  useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
    
        ProductsApi.getSearchProducts(query,setSearchResults, setIsLoading);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setError(false)
        }, 2000);
       
    }, [query]);

    useEffect(() => {
    
      clearTimeout(timer);
       
    }, [searchResults]);
```

Comment: Are you trying to handle request timeout in your components? Your ProductsApi should handle that using a promise to catch errors

Answer (score 0):

A generic answer to your problem

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [shouldRun, setShouldRun] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const TIMEOUT_DURATION = 10000;

        
        const myTimeoutCallback = () => {
            if (!shouldRun) return;
            
            // Add your logic here
            console.log("My callback was invoked after a delay.");
        };

        const timeoutId = setTimeout(myTimeoutCallback, TIMEOUT_DURATION);

        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }, [shouldRun]);
};
```

You can use `shouldRun` as a condition if the callback function should be invoked or not.

Answer (score -1):

To clear the time out you can do this: `const timer = setTimeout(() => {`.

However with your code, timer will be out of scope when you call `clearTimeout(timer)`.

You should adjust your code so that `timer` is in scope allowing access to the variable `timer`.

Comment: I tried this:``` let timer=null;

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
    
        ProductsApi.getSearchProducts(query,setSearchResults, setIsLoading);

        timer= setTimeout(() => {
          setError(false)
        }, 2000);
          
    }, [query]);

    useEffect(() => {
    
      clearTimeout(timer);
       
    }, [searchResults]);```
but still doesnt work

Answer (score -1):

Use `setInterval`

```js
function DemoApp() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = window.setInterval(() => {
      console.log('2 seconds has passed');
    }, 2000);
    return () => { 
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      My Demo Timer | Please check console.
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <DemoApp />
  </div>,
  document.querySelector("#DemoApp")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="DemoApp"></div>
```

Comment: unfortunatelly, I can not use setinterval in this case since I need the action to stop eventually and not repeat it in time :(

Comment: so if dont want to replace just replace `const timer = window.setInterval` to `const timer = window.setTimeout` :)